# To be like Codeigniter and get that view partial with vanilla PHP?

Tags: php

Just wondering if anyone can point me in the right track to imitating the following Codeigniter method with pure PHP:

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', $data, true); // where $data is an array of info to "fill in" the html on the page
```

I've started with trying to use `fopen`, but i can't quite seem to figure out the part of sending data to the file before making it the string variable that i want to eventually send to the "master template".

At current, I'm stumped. I've been looking over their `_ci_load` method which feeds the above code, but it dives into more CI libs and the whole point of this is to make the "*easiest pur php*" way. If anyone has any advice, tips, tutorial links, anything I can't already find with [Google](http://bit.ly/12rLwqs)

Comment: misplacedme nailed it, but for what it's worth, CodeIgniter is open source - you could just go look at how they do it...

Comment: @CmdrMoozy did you not read `I've been looking over their _ci_load method`? That is how CodeIgniter does it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I need something to quickly return part of a template, I use this.

```
function view($file,$data) {
    extract($data);
    ob_start();
    if (is_file($file)) {
        include($file);
    }
    $return =  ob_get_clean();
    return $return;
}
```

You should make sure to secure the contents of $file.  Otherwise, anyone can load any file they want and inject it with the data they want.  I normally use this only when I'm defining $file by hand, nothing dynamic.

Comment: only thing I can think of to make it better is to check to see if $data contains an element called data and if it doesn't unset($data) after extract.

Comment: kk, will try in a minute and let ya know how it goes, thank you!

Comment: I modified just a little to place in try catch so i can get a nice even blank string if something is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look into using the `ob_start()`, `ob_get_contents()`, and `ob_end_clean()` functions.