# How to replace input value with it's name?

Tags: php, regex

I have some input fields with name="something" and value=""

I would like to replace value="" with value="something"

How can I do it with regex? Actually, can I do that with regex?

Comment: You should never use regex to modify HTML. You can use PHP's [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: Do you just want to replace it one time (to avoid refactoring), or should it be part of your runtime logic?

Comment: If we knew why, then maybe just maybe we'd be able to help. Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: How? Type it in to the field or systematically load the field as needed based on the some server side logic tied to your database

Comment: Where do you get this input fields? Is it an ajax load? Is it a file? If we knew where in the page cycle you get these values it would be easier to determine how to do this.

Comment: Can you edit your original question and expand on it? It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. The name attribute of inputs is used for different things than the value attribute.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with inline PHP? or [this nifty little method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580396/to-be-like-codeigniter-and-get-that-view-partial-with-vanilla-php#answer-17580520)? Editing inline php with HTML is SO much easier than string html

Comment: I have a form with some input fields, but I whould like to see their name, so I whould like to put their names into their value. I got that form from static HTML file. But I have a lots of HTML files. I get them with file_get_contents and I have their names in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something in Javascript? I would grab the input name and put it into the value, quick and dirty example here: http://jsfiddle.net/c3tdLLyL/1/

```
var newValue = document.getElementsByName("inputname")[0].name 
document.getElementsByName("inputname")[0].value = newValue
```

Answer (score 2):

If this markup comes from PHP, I'd suggest use an HTML Parser for this task. DOMDocument in particular:

```
$html_markup = '
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="something" value="" />
</form>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_markup);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$out = '';
$input = $xpath->query('//input[@name="something"]'); // target that particular element
if($input->length > 0) { // if found!
    $input = $input->item(0);
    $input->setAttribute('value', 'something'); // set your value
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $e) {
        $out .= $dom->saveHTML($e);
    }
    echo $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery using `.val()` if you want to set it after the page has loaded or just PHP if you want to set it dynamically before the page has loaded?

Comment: jquery is not working sometimes for me. There are some input fields those have got special chars in their names.

Comment: For example, I have input named: `add_other[felado]` In this case jquery is not working.